# How to teach checkstyle to ignore my custom javadoc tags?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I have a custom javadoc tag (`@todo`) attached to some methods and classes. This is what  [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) says:

```
[ERROR] Foo.java[0:null] Got an exception - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
the name [todo] is not a valid Javadoc tag name
```

Is it possible to teach checkstyle to ignore these tags?

I tried to configure as specified [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html):

```
<module name="JavadocType">
  <property name="allowUnknownTags" value="true"/>
</module>
```

But got a message:

```
... cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Property 
'allowUnknownTags' in module JavadocType does not exist, 
please check the documentation
```

Moreover, I need to use these tags not only for types, but also for packages, methods, and variables.

ps. It's `maven-checkstyle-plugin` 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this property because the Maven Checkstyle Plugin uses Checkstyle 5.0 whereas the `allowUnknownTags` property was introduced in Checkstyle 5.1. (See the [Checkstyle Release Notes](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html))

Comment: Got it, thanks. Do you know how I can solve this problem in another way?